# Array of Objects/Classes fails for user defined Class

Tags: c#, c++, managed-c++

I am hoping someone with some more C++ knowledge might be able to help me. I am trying to create an array of objects in C# from a Class I've created in a Managed C++ DLL. I haven't any clue what is going on. I am able to run the application and build it setting up the array of classes appears to work perfectly fine but when I call a function from the array it never researches the Managed DLL. I've traced it and it simply doesn't work. The application doesn't fail with any errors either. Interestingly enough when I removed the array of classes and only initiated the class once it works all fine and dandy. Please help me figure out how to fix this.

```
//C#

public ClientBridge[] netlobby;

private void connectToLobby(int lobbyIndex)
{
//lobbyIndex = 0

netlobby[lobbyIndex] = new ClientBridge();

connectLobby[lobbyIndex] = netlobby[lobbyIndex].MMK_Connect(host, lobbyport);

}




//C++ DLL

// This class is the managed reference class
public ref class ClientBridge
{
    public:
        ClientBridge();
        virtual ~ClientBridge();
        bool MMK_Connect(String^ hostpass, UInt16 port);
};
```

Comment: do you get any stack trace or anything?   Can you post enough code so that we can reproduce it?

Answer (score 2):

doesn't look like you ever initialize the array

```
public ClientBridge[] netlobby = new ClientBridge[MAX_BRIDGES]; // <- gotta initialize

private void connectToLobby(int lobbyIndex)
{

netlobby[lobbyIndex] = new ClientBridge();

connectLobby[lobbyIndex] = netlobby[lobbyIndex].MMK_Connect(host, lobbyport);

}
```

Comment: Same issue. I originally had it initialized like that.